# If every object in math can be reduced to sets, how are tuples explained via sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It seems to me that tuples are just as elementary as sets. Can tuples be reduced to sets?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, they can! They are done inductively. First, ordered pairs are defined as $(a, b) = \{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$ (exercise: show that $(a, b) = (c, d)$ iff $a = c$ and $b = d$). Then, an $n + 1$ tuple $(x_1, \dots, x_n, x_{n + 1})$ is defined as $((x_1, \dots, x_n), x_{n + 1})$. Lastly, a (countably) infinite sequence, that is, an "infinite"-tuple in some sense, is defined as a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$, where $X$ is some set which contains every coordinate we want. The intuition for this is that I want $f(n)$ to define my $n$th coordinate.

Comment: I believe you mean $\mathbb{N}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes, I do. Thanks you.

Comment: Well if you're playing with $\mathbb N$ anyway, you might as well define an $n$-tuple as a function from $\lbrace 1, ..., n\rbrace$ to its underlying set.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: A function is a set of ordered pairs, no?

Comment: Absolutely, and it's worth mentioning. I don't like doing it though, mainly because it means that 2-tuples and ordered pairs are different at the set level. This doesn't matter in the long run, as both definitions fulfill the central property of ordered pairs (they're equal iff the coordinates are equal), but it still bothers me aesthetically.

Comment: The nasty part is, given an $n$-tuple $a$ and an index $i\in n$, what expression gives the component $a_{i+1}$? And remember, you need Cartesian products to define functions, so you cannot use functions in the answer, that would be cheating. Not saying it cannot be done, but it is really ugly.

Comment: Thanks, it's amazing to me how non-ordered sets can define ordered tuples like that. And I guess that means {a, b} x {c, d} = {(a, c), (a, d), (b, c), (b, d)} = {{{a}, {a, c}}, {{a}, {a, d}}, {{b}, {b, c}}, {{b}, {b, d}}}?

Comment: @csp2018 Exactly

Comment: HI, @DuncanRamage Follow up question: For this 3-tuple: (a, b, c)... Would it be {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}?

Comment: @csp2018 No. You can see why it won't be this if you consider $(a, b, a)$ and $(a, a, b)$. Under that definition, $(a, b, a) = \{\{a\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, b, a\}\} = \{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\} = \{\{a\}, \{a, a\}, \{a, a, b\}\} = (a, a, b)$ which is a big deal if $a \neq b$.

Comment: Instead, $(a, b, c) = ((a, b), c) = \{\{(a, b)\}, \{(a, b), c\}\} = \{\{\{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}\}, \{\{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}, c\}\}$.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I forgot order of elements or duplicates don't matter in sets.