# How to write a 3-tuple as sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A follow up to this question:

[If every object in math can be reduced to sets, how are tuples explained via sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3334391/if-every-object-in-math-can-be-reduced-to-sets-how-are-tuples-explained-via-set)

For this 3-tuple: (a, b, c)...

Would it be {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}?

Comment: Your question is addressed in the accepted answer in the post you linked. Is something about that unclear? Where exactly are you having trouble understanding what that answer says?

Comment: Hi, I learned how to write ordered pairs from the answer, but wasn't sure if I understood the principle I could generalize to all tuples. If the "answer" in this question is correct, I would feel I got the point.

Answer (score 1):

If you can prove that 
$$\big\{ \{a\},\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\} \big\} = \big\{ \{a'\},\{a',b'\},\{a',b',c'\} \big\}$$
 if and only if $a=a'$, $b=b'$ and $c=c'$, then $$(a,b,c):=\big\{ \{a\},\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\} \big\}$$ is a good definition!

In general, there is no single definition, anyone who serves its purpose is good.  Another well known is the recursive definition
$$(a,b,c):=((a,b),c)$$

Comment: But as it turns out, the required property is false, so it is *not* a good definition.  For example, $\{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 1, 1 \}, \{ 1, 1, 2 \} \} = \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 1, 2 \}, \{ 1, 2, 2 \} \} = \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 1, 2 \} \}$ yet it does not hold that $1=1 \wedge 1=2 \wedge 2=2$.

Comment: That's why I said "if you can prove...". And my point was not that, it was to emphasize that the definitions are not unique and any of them is good if it works as we want it to work.

Comment: @DanielSchepler In your example, wouldn't they be (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2)?

Comment: No, I mean that for example that with the proposed definition, $(1, 1, 2) = \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 1, 1 \}, \{ 1, 1, 2 \} \} = \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 1 \}, \{ 1, 2 \} \} = \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 1, 2 \} \}$ and similarly $(1, 2, 2) = \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 1, 2 \}, \{ 1, 2, 2 \} \} = \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 1, 2 \}, \{ 1, 2 \} \} = \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 1, 2 \} \}$ so by transitivity $(1, 1, 2) = (1, 2, 2)$.